# failed to create simple file explorer with vuejs and electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, electron

i've a project created with vuejs and electronjs.
here's link to my project:
https://github.com/dhanyn10/multiple-file-manager-2
in this project  i create function like a file explorer to display list of file/folder. when we run the application, click browse, and choose a folder, application works fine, just for one time browsing. Meanwhile, when I did a few browsing to test it, it failed. sometimes the application cannot display a list of files in the folder that has the contents after opening an empty folder, and vice versa. I tried to find out maybe there was an error through the developer tools, there wasn't any error message.
So, the question is, where is the error, or is there a limitation of vuejs in handling applications that are packaged in electrons?
Thank you for your attention.

[UPDATE]
here's the link to testing video that will explain my problem:
[mfm testing program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16y0wLCeaR8-n_lo7tJhyvtFLPgQ76nMy/view?fbclid=IwAR2jglvxDJx4bY0uv0KspoOtb8s3V9EpKFz0eqBvl9amOawqlhX-hyI4j10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already asnwered here [get length value from vue observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563087/get-length-value-from-vue-observer)
so, the problem coming from nodejs file system function. from previous project i've used `fs.readdir` which is async function, solved by change to sync function.