# get length value from vue observer

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, electron

i've developing electron apps with [vue-cli-plugin](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder). when print an array it's return observer.

what i do:

```js
console.log(this.listfile)
```

output from developer tools

```js
[__ob__: Observer]
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
2: {__ob__: Observer}
3: {__ob__: Observer}
4: {__ob__: Observer}
5: {__ob__: Observer}
6: {__ob__: Observer}
7: {__ob__: Observer}
8: {__ob__: Observer}
9: {__ob__: Observer}
10: {__ob__: Observer}
11: {__ob__: Observer}
12: {__ob__: Observer}
13: {__ob__: Observer}
14: {__ob__: Observer}
15: {__ob__: Observer}
16: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 17
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(17), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

how to get this: `length: 17` ?
[update]
more code

```js
    data () {
        return {
            listfile: [],
            isActive: false,
            isDataExist: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        listData: function () {
            //electron filesystem
            const fs = require('fs')
            var dirLocation = this.listData.replace(/\\/g, "/")
            console.log(dirLocation)
            fs.readdir(dirLocation, (err, file) => {
                file.forEach( (filename) => {
                    this.listfile.push({name: filename, selected: false})
                })
            })
            console.log(this.listfile.length)
            // this.isDataExist = true;
            // Object.assign(this.$data, getInitialData());
        },
        deep: true
    },
```

listfile is an array, initiated inside `data(){}` then data from filesystem(fs) inserted to `listfile` with `push()`

i've trying code:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.listfile))
```

and only return `[]`

Comment: Do `this.listfile.length`?

Comment: @Terry return 0

Comment: Perhaps try showing us a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Comment: @Terry i'm updated the question

Comment: fs.readdir is async, which is why when you console.log below it its showing 0, do it inside the resolve callback, under the forEach, or use async/await

Comment: can i keep the `this.listfile.length` outside from `fs.readdir`?
where do i put async/await?
@LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[readdir is async](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) this means you have no guarantee when it gets executed.

```
watch: {
  listData: function () {
  // electron filesystem
  const fs = require('fs')
  var dirLocation = this.listData.replace(/\\/g, "/")
  console.log(dirLocation)
  fs.readdir(dirLocation, (err, file) => {
    file.forEach((filename) => {
      this.listfile.push({name: filename, selected: false})
    });
    console.log(this.listfile.length); // works
   });
   // This line is executed before `file.forEach()`
},
```

[readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) is the syncronous alternative.

```
watch: {
  listData: function () {
  // electron filesystem
  const fs = require('fs')
  var dirLocation = this.listData.replace(/\\/g, "/")
  console.log(dirLocation)
  var file = fs.readdirSync(dirLocation);
  file.forEach((filename) => {
    this.listfile.push({name: filename, selected: false})
  });
  console.log(this.listfile.length); // executed after the above code has run
},
```